# Structure of a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I am learning how to create a function in R, but I am struggling to understand how to write  `for` loop. My understanding is that

```
for (item I list_items) {

do_something(itemn)
```

}

I would like to write a for loop to replace with `333` the cells that are equal with `123`. So the item is `123` and the list of items is the df from `sec1 till sec4`.

Could somebody explain this to me, please? And how this can be included in a function?

Sample code:

```
structure(list(sec1 = c(1, 123, 1), sec2 = c(123, 1, 1), sec3 = c(123, 
0, 0), sec4 = c(1, 123, 1)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    sec1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), sec2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sec3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), sec4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it would work for one column of your data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(sec1 = c(1, 123, 1), 
                      sec2 = c(123, 1, 1), 
                      sec3 = c(123, 0, 0), 
                      sec4 = c(1, 123, 1)), 
                 spec = structure(list(cols = list(                                                                              
                      sec1 = structure(list(),   
                      class = c("collector_double", "collector")),   
                      sec2 = structure(list(), 
                      class = c("collector_double","collector")),
                      sec3 = structure(list(), 
                      class = c("collector_double", "collector")), 
                      sec4 = structure(list(), 
                      class = c("collector_double","collector"))), 
                 default = structure(list(), 
                      class = c("collector_guess","collector")), 
                      delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  
                      row.names = c(NA,-3L), class = 
                 c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  dat$sec1[i] <- ifelse(dat$sec1[i] == 123, 333, dat$sec1[i])
}
dat
#>   sec1 sec2 sec3 sec4
#> 1    1  123  123    1
#> 2  333    1    0  123
#> 3    1    1    0    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To replace all of them, using `for` loops, you could do a double loop over columns and rows.

```
for(j in names(dat)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
    dat[[j]][i] <- ifelse(dat[[j]][i] == 123, 333, dat[[j]][i])
  }
}
```

Of course, as others have identified, you certainly don't need a for loop to accomplish this.

Comment: thanks but what if I would like to replace all "123" with 333. So at sec1, sec2,sec3 and sec4?

Answer (score 3):

We do not need a for loop here:

```
df[df==123]<-333
```

If we really need for loops:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    df[i][df[i]==123] <-333
 }
```

**output**

```
df

# A tibble: 3 x 4
   sec1  sec2  sec3  sec4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   333   333     1
2   333     1     0   333
3     1     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to DaveArmstrong Answer this would work for all rows and columns:

```
dat <- structure(list(sec1 = c(1, 123, 1), sec2 = c(123, 1, 1), sec3 = c(123, 
                                                                  0, 0), sec4 = c(1, 123, 1)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                                                                    sec1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
                                                                    )), sec2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                           "collector")), sec3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), sec4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  
  for(j in 1:ncol(dat)){
  
  dat[i,j] <- ifelse(dat[i,j] == 123, 333, dat[i,j])
  
    }
  }
```